# Can't access Excel VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with some VBA code. That code also includes a Form that is displayed on auto_open() call.

I never had problems opening VBA code form developers tab before. But now when I open that file it automatically calls the auto_open() (the form is displayed) and I can't access the code anymore. If I close the form the file is closed as well.

This problem started when I shut down Excel from the task manager because the VBA code was hanging. Since then I couldn't access the VBA for ANY other file containing forms loaded from auto_open().

NOTE: I already tried opening the file with the Shift key hold.

What is the problem? How can I access to the VBA macros as I used to do?

Thanks
Miguel

Comment: You mean the IDE will not open?

Comment: Have you tried open it in *safe* mode? In command prompt, go the path of *EXCEL.EXE* and then `EXCEL.EXE /safe`. Also try open a copy of the file from different folder.

Comment: Didn't work either. Check my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I managed this:

Rather than double-clicking the file in Windows I did:

1. Opened Excel
2. File -> Open
3. Browsed the file and hold the "shift" key while clicking on "Open". (continue holding it until the workbook finishes loading)

Answer (score 0):

Pressing shift and break key, should open up the code and then you can click the stop button and edit as you like. This has worked for me several times where I have auto_open method with a user form. The other alternative would be to change the trust settings to always ask, that would stop any macro running. You could then access code in usual way.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't wok for me. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was all of the procedures appeared on different sheets, no matter what I did I could not bring them over to one sheet. I studied the screen and my solution is as follows.

**SOLUTION FOR PROCEDURES BEING ON DIFFERENT SHEETS:**
In the lower left corner of the code sheet you will see **two** icons with lines. One is for "**Procedure**" view and the other is for "**Full Module**" view.

I always use the "Full Module" view but at some point I clicked "procedure".

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.